# why is my html page freezing firefox on reload?

Tags: html, firefox, reload, freeze

I have a page that works as it should in chrome and edge, and used to work fine in firefox before.
I made a copy of the html code generated here :

http://100monos.com/test/BreaksFirefox.html

and one without JS here:

http://100monos.com/test/BreaksFirefoxNoJs.html

If you open any of the two with chrome there is no problem, but firefox will load it the first time, then will hang on reload, showing the spining wheel animation and even freezing if you let it long enough.
(sometimes you have to reload more than once to see the abnormal behavior)

I saved a copy originally to test if it was something with the php or js code, but even without it firefox will hang.

I have tested this in 3 windows pcs with mozilla firefox 68 + and all show the same behavior. The android version doesn't, it seems.

¿Do you have any idea of what it can be, what can I do or if it is an error in the last firefox update?

Comment: Page doesn't freeze on me, using FF on mac. Since you have no idea what could be causing this, but It's simple to figure it out, just start removing component one by one until the page does not freeze anymore

Comment: I tested it in windows, It's really strange, because I removed all php code and all js, tested the page with a validator till there was no problem. And Firefox will sometimes reload it just okay, then all of a sudden you can't load the page anymore. It's not even too big, is less than 4mb.

Comment: Honestly an image of 2500x1000 is probably already a couple of megs but it shouldn't crash the browser. Is your FF updated?

Comment: I have tested this in 3 windows pcs with mozilla firefox 68 + and all show the same behavior. The android version doesn't, it seems.

Comment: start removing html section by section, first remove all css, could be css

Comment: Just for the information, my Firefox froze on the first load. So the reload isn't needed to reproduce the bug.

Comment: Mmmm. It's early but it can be something with my personalized css, after removing that section it seems to work fine. I will start adding rules one by one. All the same I think it is an error with FF.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the reason, after removing this css code the page reload without problem.

```
    .hijos{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

I think that firefox in windows may be having problems dealing with nested flex elements. All this is just speculation.